# Why should i define a parent child relationship

Tags: elasticsearch

**Parent/Child Relation:**

1. Define the relationship when there exist parent & child relation between documents and number of children are significantly high & frequent changes in docs are expected (Nested -> Low cardinality of sub-doc & read-intensive).
2. I defined the parent/child relationship between account (parent) & subaccounts(children)

> ```
>  {
>   "mappings": {
>     "_doc":{
>     "properties": {
>       "id": {
>         "type": "keyword"
>       },
>       "name": {
>         "type": "keyword"
>       },
>       "my_join_field": { 
>         "type": "join",
>         "relations": {
>           "account": "subaccount" 
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   }
>   }
> }
> ```

3. I defined few accounts & subaccounts

> ```
> PUT account/_doc/1?refresh&routing=1
> {
>   "name": "Blaze pizza",
>   "my_join_field": {
>     "name": "account" 
>   }
> }
> ```

```
PUT account/_doc/2?refresh&routing=1
{
  "name": "Blaze pizza - Denver",
  "my_join_field": {
    "name": "subaccount",
    "parent":1
  }
}
```

4. I delete the parent document using _delete_by_query API

   **Outcome:** Parent document is deleted, child document still exists.

**Question:**

1. Why should I even define a parent/child relationship when there are no constraints & we can remove parent without even deleting children?

**Note:** I have done exploration on my end before asking this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you should already know, Elasticsearch is not a relational database.
And the concept of parent / child in an index is pretty basic.
And Elastic don't plan to add such a functionality :
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/1954

So if you want to delete all children of a parent you'll need to implement a _delete_by_query by yourself.

The advice with Elasticsearch will always be to avoid parent child and  [denormalize](https://medium.com/@jeremy.gachet/denormalization-for-elasticsearch-index-984ce7cfa50a) when you can, but I can understand that your use case is good for a parent/child structure.

But parent/child give some possibilities like inner_hits that make you able to get a parent with all his childs in on query, filter on a field present in the parent. You can see a good article here [blog.mimacom.com/parent-child-elasticsearch](https://blog.mimacom.com/parent-child-elasticsearch/)

Comment: I understand that ES is not relational. What are the benefit of defining parent/child mapping over managing it yourself. e.g By defining parent_id in each doc?

Comment: The benefit is in updates and in some really rare cases in performance.
If your Parents are updated a lot, it's better to avoid update all documents each time. If you have few parents with a lot of child, (high cardinality) it can be a good deal. But in most case you should note use it

Comment: I understood your point. But in such cases, we don't need a parent/child mapping. just define parent_id field using which parent to child & child to parent navigation is possible.

Comment: You have few options with the parent/child like inner_hits that make you able to get a parent with all his childs in on query, filter on a field present in the parent. You can see a good article here https://blog.mimacom.com/parent-child-elasticsearch/ hope it helps

Comment: Jay - the article really helped. Thank you so much. ES definitely provides capabilities for parent/child mapping, which would be otherwise difficult if we explicitly maintain parent/child without mapping definition. One such example would be finding all the parents having at least 2 children. Can you please add the link in the answer so that i can mark the question as answered ?

Comment: I added the link and the comment

Answer (score 1):

Article ([Parent/Child mapping in ES](https://blog.mimacom.com/parent-child-elasticsearch/)) shared by @JayCreation brought some clarity to me on this one.

There are some capabilities (query support) which E.S provides which would otherwise be difficult to implement if parent/child relation is maintained explicitly without mapping definition.

e.g Find all the parents having more than 2 children.

```
>       {
>       "query": {
>         "has_child": {
>           "type": "subaccount",
>           "query": {
>             "match_all": {}
>           }, 
>          "min_children": 2
>         }
>       }
>     }
```